# Safari Reading list disappeared on Mac

Tags: macos, icloud, safari

Suddenly, my Safari Reading List is completely empty on my Mac (OS X 10.10.2 Yosemite, Safari 8.0.4). 
I already tried turning iCloud syncing for Safari on and off again, clearing the Safari cache,... 
On my iPhone, the reading list is still filled with items.

Does anyone has a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file that houses your reading list (and bookmarks) is called Bookmarks.plist and it is located in ~/Library/Safari/.
You could restore it via TimeMachine or any other backup you are (hopefully) running.

Comment: I hadn't thought of Time Machine yet, will try this out tonight, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I was able to restore the missing items, but iCould synchronization is still spotty.

Comment: Perhaps try to throw out all devices and enable it again after that. Make sur e to delete the items from all device but one first so you don't end up with everything double or tripple.

Answer (score 2):

I tried deleting the cache, etc., to get the reading list back but it wasn't until A VERY SIMPLE THING worked---scroll with two fingers up/down the space under the reading list icon and see the "All/Unread" tabs.  Click on "all" and presto! they had been
"read" at one time or other, and reappeared; or, I guess, click "Unread" if they are unread to make the unread reappear.  I have no idea how they disappeared (probably by my cat) but that's how it worked for me.   BTW, I was not smart enough to figure this out myself.  This fix was entirely due to a helpful person at the Genius Bar
in Marlton, NJ.

If this still doesn't work please also note that he showed me that my reading list was in my iPhone cloud
under Settings> iCloud, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The list just comes back be patient.

Comment: Sadly, this fixes many iCloud issues I have experienced personally. Either make a cup of tea and check in 25 minutes or wait until tomorrow are both great options if you haven't given it time to catch up to the cloud changes (on occasion when things get stuck).